# Import Outlook email data to Excel using Date Criteria or Subject Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I am trying to import mail data from Outlook. I'm using the code below. This code shows "Type MisMatch" error. But some of the mail is copied in the Excel sheet.

How can I import mails which have a particular subject line or mails which are received on a particular date.

```
Sub GetFromInbox()
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String, MailboxName As String
    Dim i As Long

    MailboxName = "xxxx@yyyyy.com"
    Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
        i = 2
        For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
            'For Each olMail In olapp.CurrentFolder.Items
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.Subject
            .Cells(i, 4).Value = olMail.SenderName
            .Cells(i, 5).Value = olMail.Body
            i = i + 1
        Next olMail
    End With

    olapp.Quit
    Set olapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Code is running fine for me. Without saying where you get the type mismatch error it's difficult to help. And you also ask for more code _(Is there a way to we can export mail which have a particular subject line only or mails which are recieved on particular date. )_  without showing any effort to solve this on your own. Therefore I do not understand why this was upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

*Use [Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook) to filter by Subject line or Date*

*Subject Example*

> ```
> Dim Filter As String
>     Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
>                        Chr(34) & " Like '%Bla Bla%'"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>Applies a filter to the Items collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>This method is an alternative to using the **[Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-find-method-outlook)** or [**FindNext method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-findnext-method-outlook) to iterate over specific items within a collection. The **[Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-find-method-outlook)** or **[FindNext methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-findnext-method-outlook)** are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.</sub>*

---

> ```
>  "Type MisMatch" error
> ```

*Outlook Inbox/Folder has different type of object **`MailItem, AppointmentItem, ContactItem, etc`** So the `error` could be you're hitting an item that's not a MailItem.*

*Try*

> ```
> If TypeOf olMail Is Outlook.MailItem Then
> ```

---

*So your code should look like this*

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFromInbox()
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim Pst_Folder_Name As String, MailboxName As String
    Dim i As Long

    MailboxName = "xxxx@yyyyy.com"

    Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                           Chr(34) & " Like '%bla bla %'"

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"

         i = 2

        For Each olMail In Fldr.Items.Restrict(Filter)
            If TypeOf olMail Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                DoEvents
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.Subject
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = olMail.SenderName
                .Cells(i, 5).Value = olMail.Body
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next olMail
    End With

    olapp.Quit
    Set olapp = Nothing
End Sub
```